# What does "Handy-Signal" mean?

Tags: translation

Google translate tells me that the German for *mobile phone signal* is *Handy-Signal*. Is that right? It sounds a bit odd and I was wondering if anyone can tell me whether it is correct.

Answer (score 8):

In German we call a cell phone »Handy«. As far as I know it has nothing to do with the English word »handy«. The German word »Handy« was created in the 1980'ies and comes from English »handheld«. And this also the reason for the English pronunciation of this word.

The Word *Signal* means quite the same as in English. So the term *cell phone signal* becomes *Handysignal* or *Handy-Signal* (both writings are correct) when translated into German.

btw:
In Sweden a cellphone is called a »Ficktelefon« (see http://www.ficktelefon.com), which sounds even more weird to German ears than »Handy« sounds to an English native speaker, since the German word »Ficktelefon« translates into English as »fuck phone«.

Comment: Dazu sollte man aber sagen, dass in Schweden eigentlich niemand dieses Wort verwendet - wenigstens ist es mir nie untergekommen. Gängig ist "mobil(en)".  But i agree that it sounds slightly amusing to German ears ;)

Comment: I remembered how strange it was in school to learn that "handy" - one of the few "english" words I already knew - wasnt actually an english word

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's correct. Better would be *Handysignal* without hyphen.

The German language has a feature called [compounds](http://german.about.com/od/nounsandcases/a/German-Compound-Words.htm) (exists rarely in English, you can consider *teaspoon* a compound of *tea* and *spoon*).

*Handysignal* is a compound of *[Handy](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Handy)* and *[Signal](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Signal)*.

Comment: Why would "Handysignal" be better than "Handy-Signal"?